# react native, how to jump page in network request

Tags: react-native

**I want to jump to the login page when the server returns a 401 status code，Where should i set**

my app.js:

```
...
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Test from './pages/test'
import Login from './pages/login'
...


const Stack = createStackNavigator();
class App extends Component{
  render(){
      return(
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Test" headerMode="none">
              <Stack.Screen name="Test" component={Test} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
              ...
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>

      )
    }
}

export default App ;
```

**I have a request.js to handle the all request**

every page will use this axios instance to send a request

**For example**

/pages/test

```
import {test} from './request.js'
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Test extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    test()
  }
}
```

request.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://192.168.10.10:51000',
});
instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    if(error.response.status === 401){
      /*
        *** jump page
      */
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

export function test() {
  return instance.get('/test');
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use react context to jump the screen. So two stacks will be shown conditionally in your application root - one when logged in and one when logged out. So you just change the context on 401 to signedout to switch to logged out stack.

Comment: The is perfect tutorial for you - auth tutorial starts at 21:00 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQVCkqvU1uE

Comment: Thanks for your advice，I will watch the video you provided to solve this problem, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first,Create a new file named RootNavigation.js：**

```
import React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
    navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

**and then,Import in app.js，Then add ref={navigationRef} in the NavigationContainer of app.js**

```
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

// ...

class App extends Component{
  render(){
      return(
          <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
            
          </NavigationContainer>

      )
    }
}
```

**Finally, modify request.js like this**

```
import * as RootNavigation from './RootNavigation';

// ...
if(error.response.status === 401){
    RootNavigation.navigate('Login');
}
```

**done,It works**